# Asterisk callback with IVR survey

Tags: callback, asterisk, survey, ivr

I´m pretty now to all this Asterisk-thingy and I wonder, is there a way how to call a user back from asterisk after he ended (hangup) call and give him a IVR survey, then save results somewhere (in form of audio records or DTMF inputs) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there are alot of way to do that. But all require understanding of how asterisk works.

1. Hangup events can be detected by "h" extensions something like this

   > exten => h,1,System(/etc/asterisk/create_callback.sh)
2. After that you have create script for callback, see

   http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out
3. You need create IVR in your dialplan
     http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Dialplan+Introduction

Answer (score 0):

If you have programming experience you can use AMI(Asterisk Manager Interface) to generate your calls from Asterisk to your customers, based on whatever logic. Once the customer answer the call all you have to do is redirect it to your IVR context.

For the IVR(survey) portion, you may want use AGI(Asterisk Gateway Interface). You can access both APIs with virtually any programming language. Take a look of the following:

- [Adhearsion](http://adhearsion.com/) (Ruby)
- [Asterisk-Java](https://blogs.reucon.com/asterisk-java/) or [Astive Toolkit](http://astivetoolkit.org) (Java)
- [PHPAGI](http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/) (PHP)

Good luck.